# Need Regex match pattern

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a string which i need to parse using Regex class of `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.
I need to find if the first 2 characters of the string are either "00" or "07" or "16" or "23".
Please let me know as what the pattern would be to match the above.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
^(00|07|16|23).*
```

As seen on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/yhJOH82bDk)

Comment: thanks to all who viewed and of course to all those who helped me out especially "NullUserException". the following code did really work - "^(00|07|16|23).*"